# Too many arguments to Public Sub New( ) error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

My application uses SecuGen Hamster IV Fingerprint scanner 
All of my code runs correctly except this line:

> m_FPM = New SGFingerPrintManager(device_name)

my code:

```
Imports SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows
    Public Class Form1
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
        Dim m_FPM As SGFingerPrintManager



        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim device_name As SGFPMDeviceName
            device_name = SGFPMDeviceName.DEV_FDU04
            m_FPM = New SGFingerPrintManager(device_name)

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        End Sub
    End Class
```

.NET Programming Manual

> 2.2. Initializing SGFingerPrintManager Object If an SGFingerPrintManager object is created, it should be initialized using
>   Init(SGFPMDeviceName devName) or Init(Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32
>   dpi). Init(SGFPMDeviceName devName) takes the device name, loads the
>   driver that corresponds to the device name, and initializes the
>   fingerprint algorithm module based on device information. Init (Int32
>   imageWidth, Int32 imageHeight, Int32 dpi) takes image information to
>   initialize fingerprint algorithm module. It does not load device
>    driver.

• Initiailize SGFingerPrintManage with device name The

> Init(SGFPMDeviceName devName) function takes a device name as a
>   parameter. Based on the device name, the SGFingerPrintManager loads
>   the required device driver module and initialize extraction module and
>   matching module based on device information. The following table
>   summarizes the relationships between device type, device name, loaded
>   device driver, and initial image size when the Init(SGFPMDeviceName
>   devName) function is called.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions that you included in your question say that you should call the `Init` method with a `SGFPMDeviceName` argument after you have created the `SGFingerPrintManager` object. It sounds like you want the following code:

```
m_FPM = New SGFingerPrintManager
m_FPM.Init(device_name)
```

Comment: thank you but the manual say this [VB.NET]
Dim m_FPM As SGFingerPrintManager 'member variable
…
Dim device_name As SGFPMDeviceName
device_name = SGFPMDeviceName.DEV_FDU02
m_FPM = New SGFINGERPRINTMANAGER(device_name)

Comment: @J.S.O If the manual says to code `m_FPM = New SGFingerPrintManager(device_name)` and when you do that the compiler says you vane called Sub New with too many arguments, we have to conclude that the manual is either wrong or it refers to a different version of the class than the one you are using. Did you try calling New with no arguments and then calling the Init method as I suggested?